# dc.js composite chart toggle chart

Tags: dc.js

Is there a way to **toggle charts on/off in a composite chart**?

If I hover over Legend the respective chart is highlighted but it would be nice if we could choose which ones to display (hide/show with Legend, check boxes etc).

I did find reference to [hideStack](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.stackMixin.html#hideStack) but I don't think this is what I need.

Any ideas?

(Current DC Version: **2.0.0-alpha.2**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, legend toggling is currently focused on stacks and not the subcharts of a composite chart.

It may be possible to hack the legend's toggling system, but here is a solution that just adds the toggling functionality as an extension.

We'll just wait until the chart is drawn with the `pretransition` event, then add our own click handler to each of the legend items. This will use the index of the legend item to create the selector for the corresponding subchart, then toggle its css visibility:

```
function drawLegendToggles(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('g.dc-legend .dc-legend-item')
    .style('opacity', function(d, i) {
      var subchart = chart.select('g.sub._' + i);
      var visible = subchart.style('visibility') !== 'hidden';
        return visible ? 1 : 0.2;
    });
}

function legendToggle(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('g.dc-legend .dc-legend-item')
    .on('click.hideshow', function(d, i) {
      var subchart = chart.select('g.sub._' + i);
      var visible = subchart.style('visibility') !== 'hidden';
      subchart.style('visibility', function() {
        return visible ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
      });
      drawLegendToggles(chart);
    })
  drawLegendToggles(chart);
}

composite
  .on('pretransition.hideshow', legendToggle);
```

In addition, we'll set the legend item translucent to indicate that the item is hidden.

We want to do this for all items, instead of in response to the click event, because it's more reliable to separate actions from drawing, and draw based on data. In particular, this handles the case where something else (for example an external filtering or zooming event) causes the legend to redraw.

Comment: This is like a touch of magic. Where would I put my chart name (myCompositeChart) to point it to the right one? Thanks as always.

Comment: In my example, I called the javascript chart object `composite` - if this is what you're asking, you just need to change the first word of the above block. (I intentionally use just `chart` inside so that it's easier to copy and paste this.)

Comment: so where I have:  **var myCompositeChart = dc.compositeChart("#Viz_Main2");**  etc, the extension would be:     **myCompositeChart.on('pretransition.hideshow', function(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('g.dc-legend .dc-legend-item')
    .on('click.hideshow', function(d, i) {
      var subchart = chart.select('g.sub._' + i);
      var visible = subchart.style('visibility') !== 'hidden';
      subchart.style('visibility', function() {
        return visible ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
      });
      d3.select(this).style('opacity', visible ? 0.2 : 1);
    });
});**

Comment: I think so. I like to add event listeners after initializing the chart but before rendering, in separate statements. But it doesn't really matter as long as it's before rendering. Does it not work for you?

Comment: No, it fails: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined** on this part in dc:                                                           M.prototype.on = function(n, t) {
        var e = n.indexOf(".")
          , r = "";
        if (e >= 0 && (r = n.slice(e + 1),
        n = n.slice(0, e)),
        n)
            **return arguments.length < 2 ? this[n].on(r) : this[n].on(r, t);**
        if (2 === arguments.length) {
            if (null == t)
                for (n in this)
                    this.hasOwnProperty(n) && this[n].on(r, null);
            return this

Comment: Oh, you're using a pretty old version of dc.js which doesn't have the `pretransition` event. Please use the stable 2.0 release (currently 2.0.2). There should not be any breaking changes, even though the releases are a couple of years apart.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This fixed the issue. Used [v2.0.2](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/releases/tag/2.0.2). Really appreciate your support (as always).